# Hide information in my sortable list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable

my current scenario is like this :

I have a unordered list which is sortable . I have a sentence inside each li.My problem is checking ordering of li items :

eg:

```
  <ul class="block">
            <li>A wolf was groaning due to pain</li>
            <li>crane was ready to help wolf</li>
            <li>he asked crane for help</li>
            <li>crane removed bone</li>
            <li>wolf did not reward crane.</li>
        </ul>
```

the li's will always be in shuffled order . (So storing info about each sentence became important).

**According to my database,**

"A wolf was groaning due to pain" is **3rd** sentence ...,

"crane was ready to help wolf "  is **5th** sentence

> I want to hide information about sentence order in my li ..

These are ways I can currently think of :

**1.** Store order in li id eg :

```
<li id="3">A wolf was groaning due to pain</li>
```

**2.** Use input type = hidden and store information in that

However I am not sure even second way will be efficient 
I dont want in any case user can see what is order via view source or firebug too..

So,can anybody tell me how can I do it?

NOTE : I have sentences and ordering in db.

Comment: So, what's the problem/Question..?

Comment: can anybody tell me how can I do it right way?

Comment: You can bind info in an element as `id`, `class`, `data-` attributes etc...

Comment: still if i do view page source i can see it right? that what i dont want.. That i have mentioned in 1st way

Comment: If no-one is allowed to see order you need to do all processing on the server. Any processing done in the browser can be retrieved.

Comment: use jQueries [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function, it won't be visible in source i guess :v ...

Comment: @T J: there are plugins for viewing data stored on an element. Also I could do `console.log($('li').data());` in my console.

Comment: @Blaise yea, ikr, this seems like some sort of simple game... and by the looks of the question, i don't think this requires huge security :)

Comment: its not so simple as u think  ... i have to use this throughout my application

Comment: How about creating an extra column in your database, which has a random but unique number for each row? Then you can store that random (and irrelevant number) in the source to sort and for anyone to see, because it only makes sense if you have access to the database.

Comment: Well @Banana thats a good idea ,thanks